# Display Dollar symbol($) on kendoui grid Column Value

Tags: kendo-ui-mvc

How do i add a dollar symbol before the column value in kendoui grid mvc.

Here is the code to bind that particular row.

```
columns.Bound(x => x.TotalAccountValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Format() method with the currency format code:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.TotalAccountValue).Format("{0:c}");
```

Comment: How can I use this with GBP? It shows up as dollars when I want British pounds?